# mpdf and php object

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to print the following in PDF I can not but if I know where my mistake?
This code working :

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$name = 'NAME';
$html .= 'hello Name is : ';

$html = utf8_encode($html);
include '../mpdf60/mpdf.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = TRUE;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'UTF8'; 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('Report', 'I');
exit();
?>
```

But how to deliver parameter inside the other parameter?

```
$html .= 'hello Name is : <?php echo $name;?>, this is <?php if($sex=1){echo'M';}else{echo'F';}?>';
```

or

```
   $html .= 'hello Name is : '.$name.', this is '. if($sex=1){echo'M';}else{echo'F';}.'';
```

Comment: You're already *in PHP*, what are you trying to do with the `<?php echo ?>` in there? You're also assigning here `if($sex=1)` rather than comparing.

Comment: `$html .= 'hello Name is : '.$name.', this is ';`   but and this not work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning $sex string to an extra variable and concatenate it with the string later:

```
if ($sex == 1) {
    $sexString = 'M';
} else {
    $sexString = 'F';
}

$html .= 'hello Name is : ' . $name . ', this is '. $sexString .'';
```

The else/if block can be also simplified with a ternary operator:

```
$sexString = ($sex == 1) ? 'M' : 'F';
```

You can also get some basic idea about string handling from the [PHP String type manual page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your problem then. Can you describe it more thoroughly, please?

Comment: Ok i solve a problem. 
`$html .= 'hello Name is : ' . $name . ', this is '. $sexString .''; `  THIS IS SOLEVE THANKS